# AndroidX: howto create preference grouping?

Tags: android, androidx, preferencefragment, preferencescreen

I used to have a PreferenceActivity in Android but then I wanted to migrate to AndroidX.

Now I can't find any solution to have this kind of preference grouping:

[image]

I have tried:

- PreferenceCategory (but it doesn't groups preferences into deeper levels, just visually breaks them)
- PreferenceScreen (before AndroidX it used to work, but now it just display the main settings /General, Notifications, Data & Sync/ but I cannot go deeper.)
- PreferenceGroup (but it is abstract and I have no idea how shall I implement, or shall it work at all)

### Do you have any idea on how can I get the above functionality with AndroidX Preference library?

(androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate `PreferenceFragmentCompat` per sub-screen, see the [Settings Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings#split_your_hierarchy_into_multiple_screens) for more information.